# How to call one service from another with parameter and get response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microservices

Currently, I have two services running at different endpoints. For example (this is not my real scenario):

```
StudentService
CheckHomeWorkService
```

`CheckHomeWorkService` can be used from many services (For example `TeacherService, WorkerService`). It has one controller with `CheckHomeWork` action. It has some parameters:

```
HomeWorkNumber (int)
ProvidedSolution (string).
```

It will return success or failed.

Now, In my StudentService, I have a controller with SubmitHomeWork Action. It needs to check homework using CHeckHomeWorkService and save results to a database. How can I implement this?

I was using `Ocelot Api GateWay` but it can 'redirect' to another service and I need to save the result of the response to the database

Comment: Are these services part of the same web application?

Comment: @Chetan No, they are separate WEB API application which are running in different host

Comment: You can use httpClient to call the APIs hosted on https. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use HttpClient to call the other APIs. However, if you want a more safe and performant solution, you can use also the HttpClientFactory.
[see this why to use it](https://code-maze.com/using-httpclientfactory-in-asp-net-core-applications/)
[and see the official docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

After your comment you say that you have separate WEB API services

in this case you can do this service to retrieve the result :

```
public async Task<List<HomeWorkModel>> CheckHomeWorkService(int 
homeWorkNumber, string providedSolution)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await 
httpClient.GetAsync(Constants.ApiBaseUrl + "/CheckHomeWork?n=" + 
homeWorkNumber + "&sol=" + providedSolution))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == 
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string apiResponse = await 
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HomeWorkModel>>(apiResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
public class HomeworkModel
{
  Public bool Result {get; set;}
}
```

whereas :
"Constants.ApiBaseUrl" is http address for base Url of another API

But in case of the same API you will use old solution :

you can pass "CHeckHomeWorkService" in your controller constructor ("Dependency Injection")
and call service methods as you like

Comment: Services are separate WEB API application which are running in different host

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).